# Can Google DFP show revenue based on user attributes?

Tags: google-dfp

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to determine ad revenue in Google DFP based on what group a user falls into. These are logged in users of a membership site, and there are are various tiers (e.g. bronze/silver/gold). I'd like to determine what percentage of overall ad revenue comes from each group.

I do have the ability to alter the ad serving code on a per-user basis, e.g. "if user is in the silver tier, load this code".

Is there a way to set this up?